# Group is solvable iff every quotient has a nontrivial abelian normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

> Let $G \neq \{1\}$ be a finite group. Prove that $G$ is solvable if and only if every nontrivial quotient of $G$ has a nontrivial abelian normal subgroup.

**Attempt:** If $G$ is solvable then every quotient is solvable. Let $H = G/N$ be such a quotient and
$$1 \triangleleft H^{(n)} \triangleleft H^{(n-1)} \triangleleft \dots \triangleleft H' \triangleleft H$$
be it's derived series. Then $H^{(n)}$ is a nontrivial abelian normal  subgroup of $H=G/N$. My problem is with the 'only if' direction. I thought about considering a composition series of $G$ and showing that every quotient is abelian but I was not able to proceed further.

Is my solution correct so far? How should I proceed for the 'only if' direction?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you making the unnecessary assumption that $G \ne \{1 \}$?

Comment: @DerekHolt That's how it was given as an exercise so I added it.

Comment: Why $H^{(n)}$ is a normal subgroup of $H$? I think it's just a normal subgroup of $H^{(n-1)}$.

Comment: @love_sodam $H^{(n)}$ is a fully invariant subgroup of $H^{(n-1)}$ and $H^{(n-1)} \triangleleft H^{(n-2)}$. This proves that $H^{(n)} \triangleleft H^{(n-2)}$. Proceed with induction.

Comment: Why $H^{(n)}$ is a fully invariant subgroup of $H^{(n-1)}$? Where is that fact came from?

Comment: @love_sodam In general $G'$ is a fully invariant subgroup of $G$. This comes from the fact that for a homomorphism $\phi: G \to G$ and $g,h \in G$ it holds $\phi([g,h]) = [\phi(g), \phi(h)] \in G'$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've never seen that terminology. But I still can't see why $H^{(n)}\triangleleft H^{(n-2)}$. You're considering the conjugation map?

Comment: @love_sodam Yes. The conjugation map when restricted to $H^{(n-1)}$ is an endomorphism of $H^{(n-1)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's correct in that direction.

In the other direction, argue by induction on $|G|$. Let $N$ be a nontrivial Abelian normal subgroup of $G = G/\{1\}$. Since $G/N$ clearly satisfies the same hypotheses as $G$, we conclude by the induction hypothesis that $G/N$ is solvable. Since $N$ is Abelian, this proves that $G$ is itself solvable.

Actually, I cheated a bit here by not considering the case $N = G$. It's cleaner if you don't make the unnecessary assumption that $G$ is nontrivial.

Comment: Thanks! Just to verify: If $H/N \triangleleft G/N$ then from the third isomorphism theorem $(G/N)/(H/N) \simeq G/H$ so we get the abelian normal subgroup from there. Is this correct?

Comment: You mean, why does $G/N$ satisfy the same hypotheses as $G$? Because every quotient of $G/N$ is also a quotient of $G$.

Comment: So basically what I wrote above, correct?

Comment: Are you talking about the comment? It's sort of hard for me to tell what you want to prove in it.

Comment: What you need to prove is that every quotient of $G/N$ is a quotient of $G$. That's true because if $G/N \to K$ is a quotient of $G/N$, then the composite $G \to G/N \to K$ is surjective.